# iOS XML writer class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I want to create a game, that will use a level system. So i want to store my levels and to be able to change them during the game (to save the state). So i decided to use XML for storing levels. I found NSXmlParser class for reading from XML, but i can't find a writer to save the level state. In my game the level state and the level are very similar ( i have a lot of movable objects), so i don't wan't to store the level state data separated from the level it belongs. The problem is that i can't find a way to easily modify XML files on iPhone. Maybe i'm using a bad approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the C libary `libxml2` to read and write XML. Here's a quick intro: [Cocoa Samurai: Getting Some XML Love with libXML2](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-some-xml-love-with-libxml2.html).

However, have you considered using CoreData or implementing the `NSCoding` protocol? `NSCoding` would be easier to add to existing classes.

Answer (score 5):

If you throw the data in an `NSDictionary`, you could do (with caveats):

```
[myDictionary writeToFile:pathToPlist atomically:YES];
```

Comment: this is with no xml usage, yes ?

Comment: @Andrew the resulting file will be XML (specifically, in Plist format)

Answer (score 5):

Try the open source [XML stream writer for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/xswi/):

- Written in Objective-C, a single .h. and .m file
- One @protocol for namespace support and one for without

Example:

```
// allocate serializer
XMLWriter* xmlWriter = [[XMLWriter alloc]init];

// start writing XML elements
[xmlWriter writeStartElement:@"Root"];
[xmlWriter writeCharacters:@"Text content for root element"];
[xmlWriter writeEndElement];

// get the resulting XML string
NSString* xml = [xmlWriter toString];
```

This produces the following XML string:

```
<Root>Text content for root element</Root>
```

Comment: LGPL is not (in my opinion) a good license for iOS projects. It means if I want to use your code, I'm obligated to release my application in a re-linkable form (ie. I have to release the object files, which I could do but it's a bunch of extra hassle). Have you considered using the Mozilla Public License instead? It obligates people to release changes they make to the MPL licensed files, but doesn't require the object files to be released.

Comment: The less hassle for everyone, the better. I have added the GNU all-permissive license, as it is not like any 3rd party changes will be made to the library any day soon anyways.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML). The author started in a similar situation as you and created an NSXML compatible API wrapper around libxml. He discusses the options and decisions [here](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2008/09/nsxml-on-iphone.html) on his blog.

Comment: Also, this is possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849270/iphone-how-to-write-xml-files/3973554#3973554