# Create XML from Sqlite in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, sqlite

I want to create XML from the sqlite database values in Xcode. Once I create this XML I want to save it as a string. Please let me know how can I do this? Suppose my Empl table consists of following columns:

EmplID EmplName Desgnation Department

I need to to create an XML file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EmployeeHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<EmplID>1001</EmplID>
<EmplName>Jack</EmplName>
<Designation>Manager</Designation>
<Department>Sales</Department>
</EmployeeHeader>
```

Comment: You want to do this in Xcode?  Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. I want to do it in Xcode. Once I create the XML and save it as string I need to pass it as parameters to a Webservice.

Comment: Xcode is the IDE used to develop OSX/iOS apps.  Your question has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: In my app I have a button sync. So it will sync all the details of the form which was stored in sqlite database to my central server. To do that, I have a webservice which takes string parameters. But these string values will be in a xml format. If I pass properly formatted xml as a string through the webservice then the data will be saved in the central server.What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

I thought some one wish shoot me down, but i use overloaded `-(NSString*)Description` method. Overload him in every NSManagedObject class, and then call him in root class.

If your entities don't have relationships or DataModel looks like a three, that should be work well.

Some code here:

Your entity

.h file:

```
@interface System : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * systemFullName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * systemShortName;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation System

@dynamic systemFullName;
@dynamic systemShortName;

-(NSString*)description //overload this method
{
    NSMutableString *des = [NSMutableString string]; //XML string

    //add body of object into XML
    [des appendFormat:@"<systemFullName>%@</systemFullName>",self.systemFullName];
    [des appendFormat:@"<systemShortName>%@</systemShortName>",self.systemShortName];

    return des;
}

@end
```

XMLGenerator class
.h file:

```
@interface XMLGenerator : NSObject

+(NSString*)XMLForEntities:(NSArray*)entities;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "XMLGenerator.h"
#import "System.h" //import .h files of entities you wart to serialize
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation XMLGenerator

//Out: XML string, In: array with names of entities
+(NSString*)XMLForEntities:(NSArray*)entities
{
    NSMutableString *xml = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [xml appendString:@"<start>"];

    NSInteger count = [entities count];

    if (count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            [xml appendFormat:@"%@",[self XMLForEntityWithName:entities[i]]];
        }

        [xml appendString:@"</start>"];
    } else
    {
        xml = nil;
    }

    return xml;
}


//Out: XML string for one entity, In: name of entity
+(NSString*)XMLForEntityWithName:(NSString*)entityName
{

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"We have a problem: %@", error);
    }

    NSMutableString *xml = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    NSInteger count = [fetchedObjects count];

    if (count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            [xml appendFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>",entityName,[(fetchedObjects[i]) description],entityName];
        }

    } else
    {
        xml = nil;
    }

    return xml;
}
```

Using the XMLGenerator:

```
#import "XMLGenerator.h"

...

NSString *myXMLString = [XMLGenerator XMLForEntities:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"System",<#other entities names#>, nil]];
```

If you need, i can write for you simple code how parse XML in this format to NSManagedObjects.

Comment: In my app I have a button sync. So it will sync all the details of the form which was stored in sqlite database to my central server. To do that, I have a webservice which takes string parameters. But these string values will be in a xml format. If I pass properly formatted xml as a string through the webservice then the data will be saved in the central server.What can I do for this?

Comment: You need parse XML to CoreData entities?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native nsxmlwriter and you can find the below post

[iOS XML writer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969959/ios-xml-writer-class)

Comment: In my app I have a button sync. So it will sync all the details of the form which was stored in sqlite database to my central server. To do that, I have a webservice which takes string parameters. But these string values will be in a xml format. If I pass properly formatted xml as a string through the webservice then the data will be saved in the central server.What can I do for this?